# How can i increase and decrease width and height name of the icon on Google map-v2?

Tags: android, text, paint

I am getting name of the marker on map with clarity but I want increase `width` and `height` of the marker name on map.

When I wrote marker name as 'yyyyy' then the text cutting and showing on map like 'uuuuu'.

How can I proceed? Any related links or sample code for this..

my code

private Bitmap drawTitleOnMarkerIcon(MarkingInfo markingInfo) {
        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                AddLocationTypeIcon.getIcon(markingInfo.getType())).copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

```
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bm);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.DKGRAY);
    paint.setTextSize(18f);
    paint.setFakeBoldText(true);
    paint.setTextAlign(Align.LEFT);
    paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setDither(true);
    paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
    canvas.drawText(markingInfo.getName(), 0, bm.getHeight(), paint);

    BitmapDrawable draw = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bm);
    return draw.getBitmap();
}
```

Comment: decrease your textsize or increase your canvas height.

Comment: am new to android how can i increase canvas height please tel me

Comment: try by adding bm.getHeight()+30

Comment: I tried but no use.Again getting same thing its not increasing width and height...